# Should I pass data array or input filter object to the service layer to update an entity?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

My Service layer can receive data and can update entities with ORM (Doctrine).

Now I have following question:

What should the Service Layer consume to store (create/update) a data record. Just to say: I don't want to use the Form class, only InputFilters.

I have following ideas:

**Idea 1 (raw input array)**

1. Controller: Get post/get/file data put it in an array and pass it to saveRecord of the service Layer.
2. The Service Layer will validate the data with an inputfilter and update the entity fields. When the received inputfilter is not valid it throws an exception with the error messages.

**Idea 2 (inputfilter object)**

1. Controller: Get post/get/file data and put it to a new inputfilter object. Validate it, and if it succeed pass the inputfilter to the service.
2. The service layer receive a pre-filled and valid inputfilter and update the entity fields. When the received inputfilter is not validated it throws an exception (from InputFilter anyway)

**Additional Question**
Both methods updates the entry with the given id in the data. Is it better to pass the entity ID separatly or should I pass directly the Entry Object?

Variants:

**Entry identification in data payload. Data as raw array:**

```
->saveMyEntry(array $data)
```

**Entry identification in data payload. Data as inputfilter object:**

```
->saveMyEntry(InputFilter $inputs)
```

**Entry identification in separat parameter. Data as raw array:**

```
->saveMyEntry($id, array $data)
```

**Entry identification in separat parameter. Data as inputfilter object:**

```
->saveMyEntry($id, InputFilter $inputs)
```

**Entry identification as whole entity object. Data as raw array:**

```
->saveMyEntry(MyEntity $entity, array $data)
```

**Entry identification as whole entity object. Data as inputfilter object:**

```
->saveMyEntry(MyEntity $entity, InputFilter $inputs)
```

Which method Is the best for the future?